# What is needed for these external typedefs to work in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, qt5

I'm trying to compile QT 5.11.1 on Linux. GCC is 5.3.0. C++ type option is -std=gnu++14.

In some C++ modules, there are references to external typedefs of structs and enums, defined in .h files, which do not work with diagnostics: "was not declared in this scope".

The (examples of) definitions not working so far are:

```
typedef struct hb_variation_t {
  hb_tag_t tag;
  float    value;
} hb_variation_t;
```

--not accessible from within named namespace "blink"
and

```
typedef enum { /*< flags >*/
  HB_GLYPH_FLAG_UNSAFE_TO_BREAK         = 0x00000001,
  HB_GLYPH_FLAG_DEFINED                 = 0x00000001 /* OR of all defined flags
} hb_glyph_flags_t;
```

--not accessible from within anonymous namespace.

Are there any compiler options or preprocessor directives?

Comment: are you trying to compile it with your distros version of blink or did you download some bundle that includes the webview-engine?

Comment: Usually #include directive is used for getting the things in included .h files declared in the compiled file.

Comment: Sidenote: type names ending on `_t` are [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1312382) for POSIX...

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't think he's to blame those are definitions. They're from [HarfBuzz](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/). From the other messages it seems that they're dependencies from another dependency, namely from Blink which is used as the backend for the QtWebEngine. This seems like a misconfiguration or version mismatch error, more than a C++ issue. But we don't have enough details to actually solve the issue, beyond maybe saying "compile without webview or investigate the configs in detail"

Comment: I'm compiling with almost all QT dependencies as bundled with QT source. It's confusing as some HarfBuzz typedefs *do* work, that's why I specified the referencing namespaces.

Comment: I've tried to put copies of those typedefs into the referencing C++ source, and those work (proving their originals are visible as something else), but obviously that's not a solution.

Comment: @yury10578 do you have HarfBuzz headers installed on your system from anything else but the Qt package? Maybe uninstall the -dev package temporarily or search the configuration scripts for an option to disable using the system-installed version, static linking or completely disable this option

Comment: As it happened, the QT build was indeed looking at old HB version's headers (while it was *also* reacting to changes in headers of the HB copy included with QT). As soon as I removed those, the build completed. No esoterics, no zen there. )) One would expect better handling of dependencies from the mature piece of software, but whatever. Thanks to all involved, and sorry for the noise. ))